# ESXi 5.5 CPU Sanity Check

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, central-processing-unit, vmware-vcenter

In the BIOS of my server I have 2 X 2.26 quad cores, however in VMware I only see 2 cores per CPU ?  Surely this isn't right?

[image: BIOS]

[image: VMware]

Processor Cores and Processor sockets should show as below:

Processor Sockets: 2

Cores per Socket: 4

Logical Processors 16

Hyper.. : Active

---

Answer - Cores set to dual, not all.

[image: DUAL-Set]

Comment: Can you provide the build number of your ESXi installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visit your BIOS config page and check processor settings. Do you see a value of "4" for "Number of Cores per Processor"?

Also, can you provide the build number of your ESXi installation? This could also be a bug (less likely).

Comment: I am completely unsure and confused as to whether this is a valid answer or should be a comment. Following [what I've recently been pointed at](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5316/when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) I should flag this and put it up as a likely candidate for being a comment on the OP. But as it stands I don't see any way to directly answer OP with anything that's closer to an answer than what you wrote here! You're confusing me ewwhite!

Comment: It's probably BIOS, since Dell was known to ship some of these units with [the wrong BIOS settings](http://lists.us.dell.com/pipermail/linux-poweredge/2010-February/041219.html). But this is a Nehalem-era chip, so that would be 2009-ish. The history of the server could be helpful. Was it recently installed? Was it repurposed? Just not enough info in the initial question.

Comment: Yep, correct again ewwhite.  I am still unsure why this is a function of a processor in the bios?  What benefit does limiting the cores to a machine give exactly?  Maybe just because of licensing?

Comment: @Reaces Don't get hung up on the fact that it is phrased as a question, it still includes the information that answers the problem.

Comment: @StackUser_py Sometimes people limit BIOS cores for [licensing requirements](http://serverfault.com/q/92225/13325).